# Passing multiple parameters to ClientFunction in testcafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

How do we pass multiple values to `ClientFunction()`? I tried the following ways:

Method 1:

```
 const returnVal = ClientFunction(ele,inputVal => {
      document.getElementById(ele).value = inputVal;
    });
    await returnVal(ele,inputVal)
```

Method 2:

```
 const returnVal = ClientFunction(() => {
      document.getElementById(ele).value = inputVal;
    });
    await returnVal().with({dependencies:{ele,inputVal}});
```

Both methods didn't work. Could you please help in achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish your task, I wrote the following:

```
const returnVal = ClientFunction((ele, inputVal) => {
    document.getElementById(ele).value = inputVal;
});

await returnVal('some-id', 'value');
```